# Why would multiple executions of IronPython code cause OutOfMemoryException?

Tags: memory-leaks, ironpython

I have some IronPython code in a C# class that has the following two lines in a function:

```
void test(MyType request){
    compiledCode.DefaultScope.SetVarialbe("target", request);
    compiledCode.Execute();
}
```

I was writing some code to stress-test this/performance test it. The request object that I'm passing in is a `List<MyType>` with one million `MyType`'s. So I iterate over this list:

```
foreach(MyType thing in myThings){
    test(thing);
}
```

And that works fine - runs in about 6 seconds. When I run

```
for(int x = 0; x < 1000; x++){
    foreach(MyType thing in myThings){
        test(thing);
    }
}
```

On the 19th iteration of the loop I get an `OutOfMemoryException`.

I tried doing `Python.CreateEngine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain)` instead, which didn't seem to have any effect, and I tried

```
...
compiledCode.Execute();
compiledCode.DefaultScope.RemoveVariable("target");
```

Hoping that somehow IronPython was keeping the reference around. That roughly doubled the amount of time it took, but it still blew up at the same point.

Why is my code causing a memory leak, and how do I fix it?

Comment: Which IronPython version are you using? is compiledCode created/compiled once and then reused? what happens inside the python script (e.g. could the data be added to the scope in a way other than the target variable)? Have you tried looking at it with a memory profiler?

Comment: AFAIK it's the latest version. I'm away from work right now, so I can't really check. Oh. Wow. Yeah, that'd probably do it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it turns out I wasn't thinking *at all*.

The target object object contains a StringBuilder that I'm adding lines to. About 10 lines per iteration, so apparently I can hold about 190 million lines of text in a StringBuilder before I run out of memory ;)

Answer (score 1):

IronPython has a memory leak *somewhere* that prevents objects from getting GC'd. (let this be a lesson, kids: managed languages are not immune from memory issues. They just have *different* ones.) I haven't been able to figure out where, though.

You could [create an issue](http://ironpython.codeplex.com/WorkItem/Create) and attach a self-contained reproduction, but even better would be running your app against a memory profiler and see what is holding onto your MyType objects.

Comment: "good" to know ... ;)  If there was a repro/issue I would be willing to attach a profiler to it ... but I would not exclude another reason for the objects being kept alive without more info.